# A 'SQLAlchemy' instance has already been registered on this Flask app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

On my website, I already successfully created a Flask App running with SQLAlchemy, say on mywebsite.com/test1

There is 2 files :
"main.py"

```
import sys
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, current_user, logout_user
from random import randint, choice
from setup import db, application, Table1
db.create_all()
@application.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

and

"setup.py" :

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_login import UserMixin, LoginManager
import sys
import os

application = Flask(__name__)
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=0
application.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key-goes-here'

db=SQLAlchemy(application, session_options={"autoflush": False})
db.init_app(application)

login_manager = LoginManager() #login
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.init_app(application)

@login_manager.user_loader #login
def load_user(user_id):
    return Utilisateur.query.get(int(user_id))

class Table1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Table1' (etc...)
```

Everything is going well. However when I try to create another app on mywebsite.com/test2, with the same content, I got this error :

```
File "/home/me/mywebsite.com/test2/setup.py", line 15, in <module>db.init_app(application)File "/home/me/virtualenv/mywebsite.com/test2/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 253, in init_appraise RuntimeError(RuntimeError: A 'SQLAlchemy' instance has already been registered on this Flask app. Import and use that instance instead.
```

I don't understand, how can I have already a SQLAchemy instance registered since I'm on another URL and application root?   I would like to be able to have different apps running on different URL of my website. I tried looking on stackoverflow but didn't found any solution on that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I needed to use context in the main.py file:

```
with application.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```